# R: Problem using select helper function in gtsummary package

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am using the gtsummary package to build a table of patient characteristics. I am having an issue using the selecting function `all_dichotomous`. Some variables default to showing on one line, but I want them to all show on multiple lines.

This is the code I am using, but I am getting an error.  Any suggestions? Thanks!  This data set is in the package.

```r
library(gtsummary)
trial %>%
  tbl_summary(type = list(all_dichotomous = "categorical"))
```

Comment: Can you show a small reproduciiible example

Comment: Can you check the package version.  It may have some dependency that is creating the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it!  You'll want to use the formula notation in the list, rather than a named list.  Like this:

```r
library(gtsummary)
trial %>%
  dplyr::select(response, age) %>%
  tbl_summary(type = list(all_dichotomous() ~ "categorical"))
```

[image]

There are some examples here: http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/tbl_summary.html#select_helpers